# WSO2 BPS clustering in local system

Tags: wso2

I followed http://aparnaank.blogspot.in/2014/03/how-to-configure-wso2-bps-workermanager.html   link for clustering WSO2 BPS. When all servers started and ELB showing that two members has joined.

When i click (Try It) for a web service i am getting following error

```
[2014-12-30 15:30:38,237] ERROR {org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve} -  Servlet.service() for servlet [bridgeservlet] in context with path [/] threw
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault
        at org.apache.axis2.AxisFault.makeFault(AxisFault.java:430)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.transports.CarbonServlet.doGet(CarbonServlet.java:155)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:735)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:128)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:68)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.filter.CharacterSetFilter.doFilter(CharacterSetFilter.java:61)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:178)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:49)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:141)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:156)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1653)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.get(ConcurrentHashMap.java:768)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.multitenancy.utils.TenantAxisUtils.getTenantConfigurationContext(TenantAxisUtils.java:120)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.multitenancy.utils.TenantAxisUtils.getTenantAxisConfiguration(TenantAxisUtils.java:104)
        at org.wso2.carbon.wsdl2form.WSDL2FormGenerator.getAxisService(WSDL2FormGenerator.java:702)
        at org.wso2.carbon.wsdl2form.WSDL2FormGenerator.getInternalTryit(WSDL2FormGenerator.java:112)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tryit.TryitRequestProcessor.process(TryitRequestProcessor.java:49)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.transports.CarbonServlet.processWithGetProcessor(CarbonServlet.java:182)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.transports.CarbonServlet.doGet(CarbonServlet.java:145)
        ... 31 more
```

What to i do now

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 0):

When you click on try it, what's the URL it invokes?

set proxy ports in workers nodes and see

Go to /repository/conf/tomcat/catalina-server.xml and set the proxy ports as follows

```html
<Connector protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" 
           port="9763"
           proxyPort="8280"
 
<Connector protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
           port="9443"
           proxyPort="8243"
```

Comment: http://mgt.bps.wso2.com:8280/services/SService?wsdl  this is the link it invoking. worker node giving this error

Answer (score 0):

Finally i resolved this error. This is because of SVN repo, I resolved it by configure correctly SVN repo.